# Selecting check box value using java in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox

I need to select a checkbox value from the given attachment.

The problem is that it is not desinged such a way, I can choose id of the particular value.

I wanted to find the `List` of elements under Material block and select the value cotton.

I'm very new to selenium and I tried to display the elements first using the code below:

```
List<WebElement> materialList = driver.findElements(By.id("ref_3248233031"));
boolean materiaListIsdisplayed = ((WebElement) materialList).isDisplayed();
System.out.println("Material Block is displayed" +materiaListIsdisplayed);
//System.out.println(materialList.getText()); String checkBoxEachValue = ((WebElement) materialList.get(0)).getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(checkBoxEachValue);
```

But it keeps giving the exception as below:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
>     at
>   com.jahira.addtocart.searchBedsheets.filterBedsheets(searchBedsheets.java:57)
>     at
>   com.jahira.addtocart.searchBedsheets.main(searchBedsheets.java:121)

Kindly let me know what mistake is I'm doing and also help to select the value form list of checkbox.

Comment: your list should be type safe `List <WebElement>materialList=...` follow below url
http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5330/webdriver-check-if-checkbox-is-set-and-set-it-if-not

Comment: Please format the code and the exception details properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet

```
List <WebElement> materialList = driver.findElements(By.id("ref_3248233031")); 
For(WebElement elem:materialList ){
   if(elem.getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase("cotton"){
       elem.click;
       break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Yeah..Thanks for snippet...But it gives the below exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
 
I suspect whether the is selected is wrong.. My HTML content is as below <h2>Material</h2>
<ul id="ref_3248233031">
<li class="refinementImage" style="margin-left: -10px">
<li class="refinementImage" style="margin-left: -10px">
<li class="refinementImage" style="margin-left: -10px">
<li class="refinementImage" style="margin-left: -10px">
<li class="refinementImage" style="margin-left: -10px">
</ul>

Comment: Please update checkbox `html` snippet in your question. If your are trying to check particular value of a checkbox then it should be in `<input>` tag only then you will be able to check that not by clicking any `ul` or `li` tag